# DatePicker Select by Month/Year?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, datepicker

I am developing one Simple News Application Using XML Parser Actually  what my doubt is i want see the News by Selecting Month/year.I have created the One button called "DatePickerButton" `(- (IBAction)DatePickerButton:(id)sender {})`. In My XML Url Date Format  is Coming like this `(<NEWSARTICLEDATE>14/06/2014 05:00:00 م</NEWSARTICLEDATE>)`.
Can you give any Basic Idea for this  please . ?

Thanks In Advance ..

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: Actually if i want See the Last Month or year  News By Selecting the Date picker  for Ex: I want see the last month News (May 2014)..How we can do that ? can you give me basic idea about this issue  please ?

Comment: My way is to pick up all the Newsarticledate as array. Get Index of the date, that you like to see. Call the news with this index.
<date1><news1><date2><news2><date3><news3>. If date2 == blah, get news2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a direct way, you can use the same `NSDateFormatter` to create a string of the same format as your XML entry and compare those strings. See the `NSDateFormatter` class documentation, Data Formatting Guide: Date Formatters section and http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns